# Maven - don't include a certain subdirectory of src/main/webapp in the final WAR

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

(**maven 2.2.1**)

Hello,
I have this dir tree:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       ├── **resources**
│   │       │   ├── **bootstrap**
│   │       │   │   ├── **bootstrap**
│   │       │   │   │   ├── css
│   │       │   │   │   ├── img
│   │       │   │   │   └── js
│   │       │   │   ├── docs
│   │       │   │   ├── img
│   │       │   │   ├── js
│   │       │   │   ├── less
│   │       │   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │       │   │   ├── Makefile
│   │       │   │   ├── package.json
│   │       │   │   └── README.md
│   │       │   ├── cms
│   │       │   └── **static**
│   │       │       ├── css
│   │       │       ├── feeds
│   │       │       ├── img
│   │       │       ├── js
│   │       │       └── less
│   │       ├── WEB-INF
```

Where I highlighted with double * the interesting directories...

At package time, I'm trying both to exclude `resources/bootstrap` from the final WAR **and** copy `resources/bootstrap/boostrap` inside `resources/static`.

In other words, I need to obtain the following:

```
.
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       ├── **resources**
│   │       │   ├── cms
│   │       │   └── **static**
│   │       │       ├── **bootstrap**
│   │       │       │   ├── css
│   │       │       │   ├── img
│   │       │       │   └── js
│   │       │       ├── css
│   │       │       ├── feeds
│   │       │       ├── img
│   │       │       ├── js
│   │       │       └── less
│   │       ├── WEB-INF
```

I'm unluckily messing around with the `maven-war-plugin` but still I'm unable to obtain the desired result.

Here's the latest version of the relevant part of my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/**.tld</packagingExcludes>
        <warSourceExcludes>resources/bootstrap</warSourceExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/bootstrap</directory>
                <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
                <targetPath>resources/static</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>bootstrap/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>                 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thank you in advance for any hints of follow-ups!

Comment: Might I suggest trying to adapt a bit more to the tool, rather than struggling so much in adapting the tool to you?

Comment: hey @pap, I totally agree with you. But let me explain a bit more the situation: those are minor snippets coming from a much more complex application in which I have to constantly balance between the great maven-pure approach and the needs of the application itself. In this case I have to to make sure both that people can use and adapt bootstrap while in "dev-mode" with jetty:run and that when deployed to a proper tomcat on a server, the WAR is configured (with other important pieces missing from this question) to use the static compiled bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close; you need to specify `resources/bootstrap/**` for the `warSourcesExcludes` parameter in order to omit the entire tree (the directory and all its children).  Only excluding the `resources/bootstrap` directory doesn't do anything, because it still includes all children of that directory, automatically creating the directory when it copies a child and the parent directory doesn't exist.

So your config should have:

```
    <configuration>
        ...
        <warSourceExcludes>resources/bootstrap/**</warSourceExcludes>
        ...
    </configuration>
```

And don't forget to run a Maven `clean` before packaging the war again.